# consider that ~

Tags: meaning

I have two questions.

1. I was wondering if this sentence below sounds natural.

Today's designs consider that the products have the effect on the society, culture, and the quality of the users' lives.

2. I was wondering if there is any difference in meaning between these two sentences below.

1) Today's designs consider that the products have the effect on the society, culture, and the quality of the users' lives.

2) Today's designs consider the effect the products have on the society, culture, and the quality of the users' lives.

I would really appreciate it if you answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. From a British English perspective, I would use "Today's designs take into account the effect the products have on ..." because the designs are inanimate, and are not capable of considering.

Although "Today's designer**s** consider the effect their products have on ..." seems natural to me.

2. Yes, they are different 1 is saying that the designs consider the fact that there is an effect (binary) whereas 2 is saying that the designs consider what those effects are.